# how to do balance increment and decrements on some event in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CI App where Admin creates reseller. and the reseller table has a field called Balance which is filled up by admin. Each reseller has his own users. So reseller his balance among other users.Each user can have only $5, not less and not more. So once the reseller assigns some balance to some user my code should count for 30 days.After 30 days the user balance will again become zero. And Reseller can only divide his balance among his users only. I am very confused where to start and how to do this! Please help!

The Controller:

```
    public function edit ($id = NULL)
    {
        // Fetch a user or set a new one
        if ($id) {
            $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id);
            count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
        }
        else {
            $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get_new();
        }

        // Set up the form
        $rules = $this->reseller_m->rules_admin;
        $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        // Process the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {



$data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email','password','phone','balance','user_num','address','country','country_code','created','modified','status'));


            $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);

            $key=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id);

        //here we get the last inserted record id in $last_id// 
            $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        //The logic to create blank rows in user table mapped to reseller_id    

            $values=array($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('country_code'),$this->input->post('allocation_block'),$this->input->post('user_num'));

            $key=implode('-',$values);

            $this->db->where('id',$last_id);
            $this->db->update('reseller',array('key'=>$key));

                for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'];$i++)
                {
                $userdata=array('key'=>$key);
            // here users is taken name of user table with retailer_id is field
                 $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);
                 }


            redirect('admin/reseller');
        }

        // Load the view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/edit';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }



    public function get_new(){
        $user = new stdClass();

    //          $user->id = '';
        $user->sip_username='';
        $user->sip_password='';
        $user->key='';
        $user->allocation_block='';
        $user->name='';
        $user->email = '';      
        $user->password = '';
        $user->phone=''; 
        $user->user_num=''; 
        $user->address = '';
        $user->status = '';
        $user->country=''; 
        $user->country_code='';
        $user->created = '';
        $user->modified  = '';
        $user->balance = '';
        return $user;
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

    }
```

Comment: Dont paste your whole project here.Be precise with your code while asking question.It really makes difficult to understand the exact scenario.

Comment: When a new user is created under reseller.Minus the balance from reseller account.suppose you a reseller gives 20 credits to user,deduct 20 credits from reseller account at the time of creation. For credit expiry write a cron that run every midnight and check users credit validity.

Comment: @Bugfixer Yeah I will take care of that next time

Comment: @Bugfixer when a reseller is created he asks at the same time a loop creates users so how to assign balance? because reseller asks that he want 10 users so my code creates that much blank rows in users table which are mapped by the created reseller. and maybe reseller may assign some XYZ balance to abc user.and some PQR balance?

Comment: i mean to say reseller may assign some balance to some user or even may not assign balance to other user and the max balance could be only 5 EUROS which will be reset every 30 days.

Comment: When reseller created.users are created same time ? What is the user count per reseller.

Comment: See Reseller email that he wants X users. Admin fills reseller information in registration form, which has one field user_required. now if reseller wants 10 users. then that will create blank rows in users table mapped to current created reseller. please see my code you will see a for loop

Comment: I Hope you understood my Problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86956/discussion-between-rajan-and-bugfixer).

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is time specific will need be run in a cron job.  Basically, you'll need a php script that runs probably everyday that checks for records that are over 30 days old and then update the database to 0 again.

Comment: And how to minus the total balance to users? how to differentiate current and past balance? i mean updated and previous balance

Comment: We run cron jobs by placing them in a controller called cli.php  You would have a function like decrement_balance(){.....}  By doing something like php index.php cli decrement_balance.

Comment: As far as how to deal with current and past balances.  I don't know how the data is arranged.  I would look at putting a timestamp on the various records and using that to determine when and how to handle the data appropriately.

Comment: oh So if i have base controller then i should put my decrement function there?

Comment: Yes, I would do it that way. You'll have to look up how to create cron jobs.  I've used them but I am not an expert by any means.